# Spring security password hash + salt

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, salt, saltedhash

I am working with a legacy application that stored passwords in plaintext. I have ported the application to spring 3 mvc + security. I have also successfully gotten spring security handling the authentication and authorization using sha256 + a salt based on the username. This all works great, however as part of the deployment, I will need to migrate the existing database to use the new password schema. I am not sure how spring security does it's password hashing with a salt, so i am unable to write a sql script that can be used to migrate the old plaintext passwords to the new sha256+salt schema. Is there any documentation or resources that I can use to figure this out?

Comment: Have you tried to use their http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/providers/encoding/ShaPasswordEncoder.html?You also know the salt.So did you try to see if the hashing matches?

Comment: i've tried using a sha256 generator with the salt as both the prefix and suffix, but had no luck matching the password spring generates

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is documented in [`BasePasswordEncoder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/BasePasswordEncoder.html):

> The generated password will be in the form of `password{salt}`.

So in your case you can compute the salted password using this simple code:

```
new ShaPasswordEncoder(256).encodePassword(oldPassword, randomSalt)
```

Note: [`ShaPasswordEncoder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/ShaPasswordEncoder.html) extends [`BasePasswordEncoder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/BasePasswordEncoder.html).

Comment: i'm an idiot...when I tried with the salt as a prefix/suffix i didn't include {}..thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using the default password encode then [the source](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/StandardPasswordEncoder.java) seems useful. (Pick the branch appropiate for the version you are using).
2. You can implement your own PasswordEncoder and define the way the salt is used.